# How to stop simultaneous reservations

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a simple equipment reservation system in PHP. When a user logs on they can reserve equipment. Only equipment that is not checked out is displayed to the user. Then they can add equipment to a "shopping cart". And after they have selected all the items they want they can checkout. Of course at that point I would query the database to make sure the status of those items hasn't changed. But wouldn't it still be possible for two people to hit the submit button simultaneously and cause two reservations at identical times with identical equipment?  I am looking for a strictly PHP solution if possible.

Comment: That very much depends on your database structure. How are you recording those reservations?

Comment: Without knowing how your database is structured or what DB engine you're using it's hard to give any kind of definitive answers.  However, generally speaking, transactions could potentially be a big help.

Comment: Ok I am not sure what you need exactly, but I am using MySQL.  There is a table called reservations and a table called res_items.  Since a reservation can have more than one item.

Comment: Transactions looks like it may be the ticket it is sort of like a lock that makes sure only one transaction at a time occurs?